# bypass pom.xml download in apache maven 3.8.x

Tags: maven, maven-3

How can i ask Maven 3.8.x to treat missing pom.xml as WARNING instead of ERROR

We have legacy dependencies that is working fine using Maven 3.6.x but failed in Maven 3.8.x ( Transfer Failed for download pom.xml )

Thanks

Comment: The version of Maven shouldn't matter so there must be something else that is wrong.

Comment: If you miss `pom.xml` (treat missing pom.xml as WARNING) there is something else wrong...please show the output of the failure... I suppose there is something different wrong...

Comment: You will need the pom to correctly download all (transitive) dependencies, so you can't really do without. Please show the relevant parts of your pom file (dependency, repository) and the complete error message in the output log.

Comment: i realized this is cause by maven-dependency-plugin 3.1.1 version , it works fine after i change it to version 2.8

Comment: There is another issue because if you downgrade there is wrong... without the error output its impossible to help...